# MacBook chrashing after running sudo npm install in root directory

Tags: macos, mac

I did a very stupid thing and executed "sudo npm install" in my root directory of my MacBook.
It also asked for a lot of permissions (like Desktop and Documents wich I granted)

Now I get a lot of errors from some Apple Services, my Desktop is gone, my top Bar is gone, my Bottom Menu has been reset and I cannot open finder and other things might not function right.

Any other did the same stupid thing and / or can help me out of my misery ?
Disk Utility -> Repeair sadly didn't work.

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Note for other readers the obvious answer is restore from your backup. However as you ask this I assume you have not got one. However sudo npm install should not have caused that damage, are you sure that is the only thing you have done? Also try logging in in safe mode

Comment: Of course I didn't do a backup. Safe mode starts but looks the same as when I start the Macbook in normal Mode. Finder still doesn't work and the top status bar is missing.

Comment: Why is this tagged ios?

Comment: Did you have FileVault turned on at the time?

Comment: No, FileVault is deaktivated

Comment: Still unsure how this could happen but I decided to reset my macBook air and reinstall the operating system. Following this instruction from apple: https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT212030